# Am I missing something for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I have a small issue. I can't seem to use object.create(), object.setprototypeof() or any function that is in this list:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

I'm getting a "function is undefined" message when the script trys to use object.create().

I need it mainly for a custom JS script for After Effects I found online and I have tried a verity of different script editors such as Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit, Monodevelop and VS.

Am I missing a library or something? I tried to install the latest java sdk to see if it would give me something but I have had no luck. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Trying using Object.create since it is case sensitive.

Comment: Could you please post your code, i believe its a syntax issue

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Again the code was written by someone else to export animation in after effects into another program.  
Link: http://n4te.com/x/1964-DRdD.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `Object.create` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

ExtendScript actually using EcmaScript 3, which doesn't have all the JavaScript features available from version 5.

As you can see in MDN, for `Object.create`:

> Initial definition. Implemented in JavaScript 1.8.5.

And for `Object.setPrototypeOf`: The initial definition was in EcmaScript 2015.

However, for lot of those features you can create a polyfill to support new features such `Object.create`, and sometimes MDN provides those polyfills:

> `Object.create` polyfill:

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  Object.create = (function(undefined) {
    var Temp = function() {};
    return function (prototype, propertiesObject) {
      if(prototype !== Object(prototype)) {
        throw TypeError(
          'Argument must be an object, or null'
        );
      }
      Temp.prototype = prototype || {};
      var result = new Temp();
      Temp.prototype = null;
      if (propertiesObject !== undefined) {
        Object.defineProperties(result, propertiesObject); 
      } 

      // to imitate the case of Object.create(null)
      if(prototype === null) {
         result.__proto__ = null;
      } 
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

> `Object.setPrototypeOf` polyfill:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || function(obj, proto) {
  obj.__proto__ = proto;
  return obj; 
}
```

P.S.

- As @Ozan says in the comments:

  > Trying using Object.create since it is case sensitive.
- For some functions you can't have polyfills to support those functions(but you can use transpillers, such babel).
- Some of MDN polyfills doesn't support EcmaScript 3.